# Google Apps Script - How To Publish / Install A Container-Bound Script

Tags: google-apps-script, installation, publish

I have a document container-bound script, that I would like to publish, I would like to make it available to people in my google apps organization. I know the script gallery is only available to spreadsheet apps, so how do I publish it. Or, more specifically, currently the script is bound to one document, how do I make it run on all documents? My user base is fairly small, about 300 people, and I can have each one of them install it if need be.

Thanks,
Ari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are limited options for distributing container bound scripts. When a document with a container bound script is copied, the script is also copied. So if the 300 people in your organisation copied the document they would also have a copy of that script. The issues with this techniques is that the script is only attached to that particular document and creating a new document, rather than taking another copy of the template, or opening an existing document will not include your script functionality. The other issue the script in the copies of your template becomes orphaned and you cannot push updated versions. Using [Managed Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) addresses this to a degree but the end user still needs to select the newer version of the script in the script editor.

A way to mass deploy your script in your organisation is using Google Apps Script authored [Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/). Add-ons are installed by users and become available to every document they work on. The script behind add-ons can also easily be upgraded without any user intervention. One issue with this approach is [all add-on's need to be approved by Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#apply_to_publish). This introduces a risk that Google will not publish your script as an add-on. Whilst there is a public store of add-ons after your project is approved by Google there are visibility options to restrict access and prevent there general visibility. As per [add-on publication step #12:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#apply_to_publish)

> In the "Visibility options" section, select which users will be able
>   to find your add-on — usually either all users or only users with an
>   account in your Google Apps domain.

Hopefully when add-ons leave developer preview Google Apps domains will have more control over publication and visibility (I've opened a [feature request for this](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4169))